# Is it possible to run hdp sandbox on mac?

Tags: macos, hadoop, ambari, hdp, hortonworks-sandbox

By checking some random [documentation](https://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/InstallingHortonworksSandboxonaMacUsingVB.pdf) I found by googling hdp sandbox on mac, it seems possible. I try setting the network adapter to `host-only adapter` which results in the error below:

```
Nonexistent host networking interface, name '' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Therefore, I just keep the default settings. So far, I tried with versions 3.0.1 (latest) and 2.6.5 using virtualbox and using docker, no matter what I do, I always end up with a dashboard full of red flags, and most of the services won't work because of ambiguous errors.

After a while, I get the url which I use to connect to Ambari:

[image: hdp-localhost]

For some reason, I keep getting `502 Bad Gateway` for 5-10 minutes following the screen above, followed by the dashboard which is clearly full of issues as shown below:

[image: dashboard]

Let's say, I want to upload a table using hive view I select hive view:

[image: hive-view]

I get more ambiguous errors:

[image: hive-errors]

here's the stack trace:

```
        Service 'userhome' check failed:
java.net.ConnectException: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:50070: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.connect(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.connect(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:622)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getHdfsFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1020)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$4.run(HdfsApi.java:216)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$4.run(HdfsApi.java:214)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.execute(HdfsApi.java:513)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.execute(HdfsApi.java:489)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.getFileStatus(HdfsApi.java:214)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.commons.hdfs.UserService.homeDir(UserService.java:67)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.hive2.resources.files.FileService.userhomeSmokeTest(FileService.java:256)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.hive2.HelpService.userhomeStatus(HelpService.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthorizationFilter.java:287)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.doFilter(AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.ViewThrottleFilter.doFilter(ViewThrottleFilter.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:212)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:201)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

which is equally ambiguous and useless. Many of the errors contain:

```
Connection failed to http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:<some-port>
```

So, I tried appending the following to `/private/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
```

followed by another attempt to shutdown the vm and relaunch the dashboard, I just get more problems

[image: more-problems]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, I have done it countless times, several years ago when those sandbox machines were actually maintained. They are not, anymore, though since the recommendation is to use cloud-hosted Hadoop solutions like AWS EMR, Google DataProc, or Azure HDInsights.

---

The errors you are seeing in Ambari are expected. Nothing starts, by default.

You need to actually start the services in this order before you can even use Hive.

- HDFS

  - NameNode
  - DataNode
- YARN

  - NodeManager
  - ResourceManager
- Zookeeper
- Hive

  - Metastore
  - HiveServer2

---

If you really just want something resembling "Hadoop + SQL", then install Presto/Trino, Spark, or Flink locally on your Mac

Comment: Is having 8 GB of ram and allocating 4 a problem? Because I read somewhere that limited memory is a potential cause of these errors. Given that it's not maintained anymore, so sooner or later it's going to stop working somewhere, are there free alternatives? I'm asking because i just started learning these tools, and it'd be nice to get used to them without worrying about the number of hours i need to pay for while i was technicaly playing.

Comment: I've ran the Sandbox with about 2-4GB RAM, but you need to really need to know what you are configuring and limiting running. Otherwise, yes 8GB on the VM itself just to start all the services. The tools listed at the bottom are all open-source (free).